# there is no phpmyadmin.conf in /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04) and I can't find `phpmyadmin.conf` for step two of this tutorial. I only have the following files in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`

```
charset.conf
other-vhosts-access-log.conf
javascript-common.conf
security.conf
localized-error-pages.conf
serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

I have to to edit which one?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Are you sure you followed this correctly?

> When the first prompt appears, apache2 is highlighted, but not
>   selected. If you do not hit "SPACE" to select Apache, the installer
>   will not move the necessary files during installation. Hit "SPACE",
>   "TAB", and then "ENTER" to select Apache.

This is a very important part of step one that i've overlooked before that can cause this problem

As another remedy you could try this:

**From the docs:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

> If this does not work, then you can do the following to include the
>   phpMyAdmin-shipped Apache configuration into Apache:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
> ```
>
> Since Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander), Apache no longer loads
>   configuration files from the /etc/apache2/conf.d directory. Instead,
>   they are placed in the /etc/apache2/conf-available directory which is
>   managed with the a2enconf command. Therefore, if you need to manually
>   include the phpMyAdmin-shipped Apache configuration file, you must run
>   the following:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
> sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
> ```

Comment: I must remove php my admin before that? is "sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin" enough?

Comment: I would try running the commands i suggested before hand to see if that works if it doesnt then yea i would retry the installation more details can be found here http://askubuntu.com/questions/262941/how-do-i-completely-remove-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 38):

When the first prompt appears, apache2 is highlighted, but not selected. If you do not hit "SPACE" to select Apache, the installer will not move the necessary files during installation. Hit "SPACE", "TAB", and then "ENTER" to select Apache.

**If you didn't do this, enter the following command:**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Select no to reconfiguring the database and then you will get the option to select Apache following the steps above.

Comment: Thank you ! I did the installation quickly and didn't give attention to the fact that, in addition to the red color covering the 'apache2' box, there needs to be a '*' in it

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - remember to do a `sudo systemctl restart apache2` after reconfiguring

Comment: Nice this did the job